# jQuery - After ajax load I need to disable a click() event

Tags: jquery, onclick

When a page loads it detects if the user is logged in or not. If not:

```
<a class="logIN" href="NOT_LOGGED_IN">MY BAG</a>
```

I have a click event to prevent users to login.

```
$(".logIN").click(function() { 
   $("#dialog-message").dialog('open');
   return false;
});
```

Submitting logging form:

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(response) { 
        if(response === 'successful') {
            $(".logIN").attr("href", "LOGGED IN"); //this works
            $(".logIN").removeClass(".logIN").addClass("logSU"); //this doesn't work
        }
    }            
});
```

I don't want the click event to run after the user has logged in (don't need to open dialog again). 
Because the first link is in the main page I need to change that with JS.
I've tried changing the class name associated with the click event. (classes didn't change their names)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a form with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753598/insert-a-form-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply unbind the `click` event for .logIN after user login successfully

```
$('.logIN').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Still opening dialog message despite the user is logged in. Don't know what could be happening. Changing class names didn't worked too, I mean no changes were performed.

Comment: @dstonek bear in mind that refreshing the page refresh the jquery functions too. In this case you have to make jquery ajax call to check whether user is logged in, so if he is logged in, unbind the click event too.

Comment: @Nilola Mitev When the page refreshes I detect from server (php session) the user is logged in, then the click function does not load.
If he isn't logged in div#content loads a logging form (including JS Validation script) that sends data via validate-submitHandler-ajax to server. Then a 'successful' response let the user access MY BAG, also in div#content. The problem is that the click function was loaded before the logging process and after that it must unbind. I used the sample from query unbind docs to only affect that click, unsuccessfully. href changes performed good